# hadoop how do i create an inputsplit that spans multiple blocks

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I decided to write a simple custom FileInputFormat to test my understanding of inputSplits, etc.  And the exercise has left me with a serious question.

**Context**

- Let's say that I have a very large file that is stored in HDFS across
  N blocks.
- Let's say that my splits may span two blocks (**I already KNOW why this is not a good idea - I'm just trying to improve my understanding of HDFS and `InputSplits` - so hang in there**).
- Let's say I have a method that takes a `FileStatus, FileSystem` and returns an array of `FileInputSplit`:

InputSplit[] getSplits(FileStatus file, FileSystem fs);

**Question/Problem**

I need 4 values to form a `FileInputSplit split = new FileInputSplit(path, start, length, hosts)`

I have the path, start, length, I need to get the hosts, so for each section of the file designated by the `start` and `length` I retrieve the location blocks `final BlockLocation[] blocks = fs.getBlockLocations(file, start, length);` and from the blocks I can get the hosts.

I'm not sure what I need to do if the section I'm interested in spans multiple blocks:

1. when forming the FileInputSplit do I use the `offset, length` from the `blocks[i]`
2. how do I cram two blocks into one inputSplit?
3. there is a combineInputSplit and a compositeInputSplit but not sure if it is for this purpose?

**My Guess**

I'm guessing that it doesn't matter, I'm guessing that I can use the file's start, length and just append a list of all the hosts that have the multiple blocks.  Since the record-reader will just use the fileSystem to read the file.  All that may happen is that the mapper-task may need to read blocks from a different node or rack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3293) talks about the scenario you are referring to.